# how loop through a JSON Array of bitcoin transaction data

Tags: php, json, foreach, blockchain

My code is:

```
$requesturl='https://blockchain.info/tx-index/1fda663d2584425f192eae045d3809950883ebe50f2222f98ef7d31f414f3f96?format=json';
$ch=curl_init($requesturl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$cexecute=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result = json_decode($cexecute,true);
// to get the first i use 
echo $result['out'][0]['addr'];
to get the second I use
echo $result['out'][0]['addr'];
```

Now my requirement is to look through the array using for each but its throwing error:

```
foreach ($result['out'] as $adressee) {
   echo $adressee.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: What on earth is the title of this question supposed to mean?

Comment: @duskwuff The question is simply user wanting to loop through a json response. Whether that json data is bitcoin transaction information is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for($i=0; $i<count($result['out']); $i++) {

   echo $result['out'][$i]["addr"].'<br>';
  }
```

Some Sample codes in PHP manual helped me come up with this solution